# General method of finding dimension of a ring and determining regularity

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, noetherian, krull-dimension, regular-rings

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, $A=R/(y^3-x^3-4)$ and $m=(x,y,2)$. Now I want to find out what the dimension is of $A_m$ and say whether it is regular or not. My prefered definition of the ring $A_m$ being regular is:

"Let $A_m$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension $d$ with $m$ its maximal ideal and $k=A_m/m$ its residue field. Then $A_m$ is regular if $\text{dim}_k(m/m^2)=d$ (or $m$ can be generated by $d$ elements)."

To determine the dimension of $A_m$, first we look at $R$ and $R_m$ I guess, because for determining dimensions we can interchange localisations and taking quotients. The dimension of $R$ is $3$ because $(0)\subset(p)\subset(p,x)\subset(p,x,y)$ with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ prime (is that how I write it down?). Then we know dim$R_m\leqslant3$. We have $(0)\subset(x)\subset(x,y)\subset(x,y,2)$ in $R_m$, so dim$R_m=3$. Now what is dim$R_m/(y^3-x^3-4)=$dim$A_m$? We know that $y^3-x^3-4$ is an irreducible polynomial by the Eisenstein criterion. So $(y^3-x^3-4)$ is prime in $R_m$. Maybe there's a formula we can use about some chain of ideals containing this ideal $(y^3-x^3-4)$ and the dimension of $R_m$ using the upperbound we have?

Now, say $A_m$ has dimension $2$, then $A_m$ can't be regular since $m=(x,y,2)$ is generated by $3$ elements. How to determine $\text{dim}_km/m^2$? Can we compute it in $R$ also, to generalise?

Is there a step by step plan or a list of things to consider in these kind of computations in order to solve them?

Comment: «The dimension is 3 because blah»: well, that is a chain of prime ideals of length 3, but how do you know there are no chains of longer length?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez There are no longer chains because $(x)$, $(x,y)$ and $(x,y,2)$ are prime ideals and $m=(x,y,2)$ is maximal in $R_m$ because a localisation by a prime ideal is local right?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Oh, it should be even more trivial, since the dimension is bounded from above by 3, and this chain has 3 links.

Comment: But why are there no prime ideals between (x) and (x, y)? Why is the dimension bounded by 3?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez $(x,y)/(x)\subset \mathbb{Z}y$, meaning that $(x,y)/(x)$ is simple, hence no links in between. Is that right?

Comment: I meant $(x,y)/(x)\cong\mathbb{Z}y$

Comment: (x,y)/(x) is a simple what? (x,2y)/(x) is a proper and nonzero R-submodule of that quotient.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez A simple $R$-module. The lecturer did it as quick as that, by just saying "the extension is simple as an $R$-module because the quotient has dimension 1 as a $\mathbb{Z}$-vector space."

Comment: It is not simpem as an R-module, though. A rank 1 Z-module is not simple (simple Z-modules are finite)

Comment: The chain being maximal (meaning that it cannot be enlarged) is in general *not* enough to prove that its length is the dimension of the ring. It works here because $\mathbb{Z}$ is “nice enough”, but it’s not always the case (search for the keywords “catenary” or “universally catenary”). Note that you haven’t shown that $m$ was not generated by two elements (you’ve just showed that it had a generating family with $3$ elements – maybe there’s a better choice of generators).

Comment: “Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian regular local ring and let $f \in m$ be nonzero. Then $R/fR$ is regular iff $f \notin m^2$.” This is a more general result (but perhaps easier to prove) and perhaps that can make your life easier.

Comment: @Aphelli I don't see how that helps here as we already have a ring $A=R/fR$ and then we localise with $m$.  Or is showing that $A_m$ is regular the same as showing $R_m/fR$ is regular? In this particular case it is, since $f\in m^2$ here (so $m/m^2$ is the same in $R_m$ and $A_m$), but in general?

Comment: This result says that $A_m$ is regular iff $y^3-x^3-4 \notin m^2R_m$.